# case statement in a where clause

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, where-clause

I am trying to create a where statement that considers what day of the week it is and then filters according. For example, if the day I am pulling the data is a Wednesday, I only want to pull data for Monday - Wednesday of that week. If it is a Friday, then Monday - Friday and so on.

I tried doing this using a case in my where clause, but I can't get it to work.

```sql
select 
    uuid,
    acquisition_campaign,
    REFERRAL_PROMO,
    channel,
    partner,
    created_at::date as created_date
from CONSUMER_TMP
where created_date between case DAYOFWEEK(getdate())
                                when 0 then (getdate()::date) and (getdate()::date)
                                when 1 then (DATEADD('day', -1, getdate())) and (getdate())
                                when 2 then (DATEADD('day', -2, getdate())) and (getdate())
                                when 3 then (DATEADD('day', -3, getdate())) and (getdate())
                                when 4 then (DATEADD('day', -4, getdate())) and (getdate())
                                when 5 then (DATEADD('day', -5, getdate())) and (getdate())
                                when 6 then (DATEADD('day', -6, getdate())) and (getdate())
                                else (DATEADD('day', -7, getdate())) and (getdate())
                           end
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or just the wrong results?

Comment: Please see my edit, if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test it but I think this would work.

One issue is you cannot use custom column name in `where` clause, so first you'll have to change that to actual column name. Second you'll need to change the `and` in your query like below:

```sql
where created_at::date between case DAYOFWEEK(getdate())
                                when 0 then (getdate()::date)
                                when 1 then (DATEADD('day', -1, getdate()))
                                when 2 then (DATEADD('day', -2, getdate()))
                                when 3 then (DATEADD('day', -3, getdate()))
                                when 4 then (DATEADD('day', -4, getdate()))
                                when 5 then (DATEADD('day', -5, getdate()))
                                when 6 then (DATEADD('day', -6, getdate()))
                                else (DATEADD('day', -7, getdate()))
                           end and (getdate())
```

Because the `and` in your case needs to be outside the `case` like `between something and other_thing`, for example when `DAYOFWEEK(getdate())` is 0 then it checks if `created_date between (getdate()::date) and (getdate())` and so on.

---

Edit:

As [@Simeon Pilgrim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43992/simeon-pilgrim) says in comments you can use in *snowflake* the column name from your `select`.

And I think you can even simplify your query even more, you don't need a `case` at all, you can do like:

```sql
where created_date between (DATEADD('day',-(DAYOFWEEK(getdate())),getdate())) and (getdate())
```

So if day of week is 0 it will return `between getdate() and getdate()`, because adding -0 days adds 0 days, if it's 1 it will return `between getdate() - 1 and getdate()` and so on.

Another thing with your query is `else (DATEADD('day', -7, getdate()))` I believe you can remove this `else` and add it to different day, because `dayofweek()` can only return 7 values, (0-6), so you can add the else for any other day, instead of `when then` for that day, so if my previous suggestion doesn't work, (I don't know why it shouldn't), you can simplify it with this suggestion.

Comment: Awesome makes totally sense!

Comment: You can use output column alias `created_date` in the WHERE caluse in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

The correction above will fix the case statement for the use with BETWEEN, but in following the desired results, I thought there may be an issue with the day of week logic - particularly if the intent was to get Monday->Today as long as it's within a week.

Of note, check your start of week setting, as it may not return a 0 here for start of week.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#first-day-of-the-week

I created a test case, and tested it - it appears to work per the the desired logic described above:

```
create
or replace table testdata (
    create_date date,
    c2 varchar,
    c1 int default dayofweekiso(create_date)
);
insert into
    testdata (create_date, c2)
values
    (to_date('07-10-2022', 'mm-dd-yyyy'),'Sunday'),
    (to_date('07-11-2022', 'mm-dd-yyyy'),'Monday'),
    (to_date('07-12-2022', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 'Tuesday'),
    (to_date('07-13-2022', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 'Wednesday'),
    (to_date('07-14-2022', 'mm-dd-yyyy'),'Thursday'),
    (to_date('07-15-2022', 'mm-dd-yyyy'),'Friday');
```

```
select
    current_date(),
    dayofweek(current_date()),
    dayofweekiso(current_date),
    create_date
from
    testdata
where
    (
        dayofweekiso(create_date) = dayofweekiso(current_date())
        and create_date = current_date()
    )
    or create_date between case
        dayofweekiso(current_date())
        when 2 then (DATEADD('day', -1, current_date()))
        when 3 then (DATEADD('day', -2, current_date()))
        when 4 then (DATEADD('day', -3, current_date()))
        when 5 then (DATEADD('day', -4, current_date()))
        when 6 then (DATEADD('day', -5, current_date()))
        when 7 then (DATEADD('day', -6, current_date()))
    end
    and current_date();
```

It's only Tuesday, I expect to see just Monday and Tuesday's data in the results:

| CURRENT_DATE() | DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) | DAYOFWEEKISO(CURRENT_DATE) | CREATE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-12 | 2 | 2 | 2022-07-11 |
| 2022-07-12 | 2 | 2 | 2022-07-12 |

Answer (score 0):

The first point to make is you case statement is truncating to the start of the week, so you should just do [DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html)

This code gets some days, and show with them self join how the days are in or out which is show how your `current_date()` is the same as `d1`

```
with data(date) as (
    select 
        to_date(column1, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
    from values
        ('07-10-2022'),
        ('07-11-2022'),
        ('07-12-2022'),
        ('07-13-2022'),
        ('07-14-2022'),
        ('07-15-2022')
)
select d1.date as d1
    ,d2.date as d2
    ,dayname(d1) as day_name
    ,DAYOFWEEK(d1) as day_of_week
    ,date_trunc('week', d1) as trunc_d1
    ,d2 between trunc_d1 and d1 as in_range
from data as d1
cross join data as d2
order by 1;
```

| D1 | D2 | DAY_NAME | DAY_OF_WEEK | TRUNC_D1 | IN_RANGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-11 | Sun | 0 | 2022-07-04 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-12 | Sun | 0 | 2022-07-04 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-13 | Sun | 0 | 2022-07-04 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-14 | Sun | 0 | 2022-07-04 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-15 | Sun | 0 | 2022-07-04 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-10 | Sun | 0 | 2022-07-04 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-07-14 | Mon | 1 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-07-15 | Mon | 1 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-07-13 | Mon | 1 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-07-12 | Mon | 1 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-07-11 | Mon | 1 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-07-10 | Mon | 1 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-12 | 2022-07-10 | Tue | 2 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-12 | 2022-07-11 | Tue | 2 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-12 | 2022-07-12 | Tue | 2 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-12 | 2022-07-13 | Tue | 2 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-12 | 2022-07-14 | Tue | 2 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-12 | 2022-07-15 | Tue | 2 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-10 | Wed | 3 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-15 | Wed | 3 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-14 | Wed | 3 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-13 | Wed | 3 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-12 | Wed | 3 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-11 | Wed | 3 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-14 | 2022-07-10 | Thu | 4 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-14 | 2022-07-11 | Thu | 4 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-14 | 2022-07-12 | Thu | 4 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-14 | 2022-07-13 | Thu | 4 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-14 | 2022-07-14 | Thu | 4 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-14 | 2022-07-15 | Thu | 4 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-10 | Fri | 5 | 2022-07-11 | FALSE |
| 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-11 | Fri | 5 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-12 | Fri | 5 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-13 | Fri | 5 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-14 | Fri | 5 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |
| 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | Fri | 5 | 2022-07-11 | TRUE |

Thus your SQL could be written:

```
select 
    uuid,
    acquisition_campaign,
    REFERRAL_PROMO,
    channel,
    partner,
    created_at::date as created_date
from CONSUMER_TMP
where created_date between case date_trunc('week',getdate()) and getdate()
```

This is using your system start of the week default, which by default is Sunday, now if you want Monday, you could have used [DAYOFWEEKISO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html), but there is not equivalent for [DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) (aka 'weekiso' [does not exist](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#supported-date-and-time-parts))